# Cross-referencing items within sections

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate

I would like to cross-reference items within the document structure

```
Chapter 1
  Section 1
  Section 2
     (i) Item 1
    (ii) \label{...} Item 2
```

like this

```
(1.2 ii)
```

Is there a way do achieve that automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify alternative `label` and `ref` key-values using [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem):

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}% 1
\section{A section}% 1.1
\section{A section}% 1.2

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*),ref=(\thesection~\roman*)]
  \item Item 1
  \item \label{item2} Item 2
\end{enumerate}

See~\ref{item2}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 You hit me by three minutes with basically the same example.

Comment: Thank you, this has helped me a lot ! Is there a way to enumerate sections/subsections/subsubsections in a dynamical way ? Suppose I have a document where I have subsubsections, but also subsections, and `enumerate` environments in both. If I use this solution I need to know exactly whether the list will end up in a subsection or a subsubsection, otherwise the numbering will be too short, or contain an undesirable `.0.` ... This may evolve over time, as I may, say, find it useful to include a subsubsection header before the list at a later point.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat: Try [this code](https://pastebin.com/Sha99a1M) that produces [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAMT2.png) in an automated fashion. The idea is to create an `\enumprefix` that is specific to the sectional unit that is last called (`\section`, `\subsection`, ...) and updated accordingly.